# "Старый свет", "новый свет" и "конец света" — семантика

Tags: фразеология, семантика, словосочетания, историческая-грамматика

Связано ли историческое возникновение фразеологизмов "старый свет" и "новый свет" с фразеологизмом "конец света"?

Answer (score 1):

На 1492 год был назначен «конец света». Считалось, что это 7000 год от Сотворения, а 7000 лет — это срок существования мира.

Такие выводы делались на основании того, что мир был сотворён за 7 дней, человек был создан на 6 день, для бога 1 день как тысяча лет, а Христос родился в 5508 году от сотворения мира.

Пасхалия была рассчитана только до этого года, о чём в конце делалась приписка: «Сие лето на конце явися, в оньже чаем всемирное торжество пришествие Твое».

Как ни странно, но именно в этом году Христофором Колумбом была открыта Америка (новый свет).